# Some animations in Angular don´t show up when the should

Tags: angular

I´m making an angular project. These are the modules and components I import/declare.

[image: Those are the componentes and the modules I import in my component]

For some reason when I import `BrowserAnimationModule` I get this error:

[image: Error I get]

However if I delete the BrowserAnimationsModule everythings works fine except I don´t have the animations I need.

Comment: Please always include code as text and not as image.

Comment: You've imported the BrowserAnimationsModule in AppModule, right? Next to BrowserModule? You shouldn't need to reimport .

Comment: Could you check if you haven't included BrowserAnimationModule  in you CommonModule, or any modules that already included it?

Comment: this module is independent from the appModule. For example, I imported ReactiveFormsModule in my appModule and in RegisterModule, I couldn´t use it so I imported there too.